# Qt with Eclipse CDT Juno

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, eclipse-cdt

I am having a difficult time trying to find a way to link the Qt library to my Eclipse project.

*The Qt SDK package 4.8.1
with 
Eclipse CDT Juno*

**Is there a way to link Qt libraries to eclipse?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**: It appears that the Eclipse plugin is no longer officially supported but that it's still available via download. The link below references their ftp site.

---

Nokia provides [Eclipse-Qt integration](ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qteclipse/). That said, it's unnecessary as it's always possible to use an Eclipse project that's using custom build commands. You could simply create a [makefile project](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_projects.htm) making certain to run qmake at the appropriate times.

To start, it might be as simple as:

- Create a file or two
- qmake -project # create your project file
- qmake          # generate your makefile
- # tell eclipse to build the project

If the above, you'd only need to re-run qmake when adding new files and doing other things that affect the qt project file.

Comment: That plugin doesn't seem to work with the Juno version, 32 or 64.  I am still fairly new to using outside libraries that don't come prepackaged in an IDE so i appreciate the insight and will look into doing this.

Comment: Okay I re installed the eclipse integration with 32 bit version of Eclipse Juno and it worked.

Comment: Your link is dead, do you have any idea of the new location?

Comment: I added a link to their FTP site, but it looks like the plugin is no longer officially supported.

Comment: Just a quick question before I attempt this: How does the CDT indexer get along with Qt C++ extensions?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Others would probably like to hear about your experience, so please post back if you can.

Comment: The ftp link is broken. Seems like is not going to be distributed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

@enobayram 
Yes it does.

The Qt integration pack is 32bit and therefore all depencies like Eclipse / Java / Qt must be also 32bit.